# B2B authentication best practices

Tags: authentication, rest, jwt

I'm in the process of developing a B2B (business-to-business) application. I've implemented JWT auth, and it is working as expected. Right now the authentication functions as if it were a B2C (business-to-customer) app.

I'm trying to determine the best practices for B2B authentication.

Is having one authentication account bad practice in a B2B app? For example, every employee at Company A would use the same set of login credentials.

Comment: Normally I am all "it depends on the use case!" But this is pretty much always a terrible idea. If your framework doesn't have built in user management then lookup identity providers or a SAML integration, like @multithr3at3d said

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the type of application, having only one set of credentials is certainly bad practice. For starters, since it's shared, it's more likely to be treated less carefully; e.g. written down in places where people are likely to see, and thus could more easily fall into the hands of an attacker. Once the password is compromised, it's a bigger deal to change it since you need to notify everyone.

It also greatly reduces your ability to audit user activities; without an unique user ID, you can't track who is doing what.

If the company already uses a central authentication service (e.g. active directory/LDAP) or single-sign-on (SSO), it would be ideal to instead rely on that for authentication, with the added benefit that all the user information is already there, as well as group/permission information.